# Query with multiple distinct in a column

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query on a column in a table. In column "text" I can have values of either 5 or 10 or null. I want to get count of number of rows in the table for 5 or 10 or null. I wrote following query it is not working properly

```
select COUNT(*) from t_test
select COUNT(text) from t_test where text=5
select COUNT(text) from t_test where text=10
select COUNT(text) from t_test where text=null
```

I can get first three select statements values but the last one with null returns zero while there are rows with null in it. How to write this query? Thanks

Comment: You want text IS null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use conditional summation:

```
select count(*),
       sum(case when text = '5' then 1 else 0 end) as Num_5,
       sum(case when text = '10' then 1 else 0 end) as Num_10,
       sum(case when text is null then 1 else 0 end) as Num_Null
from t_test;
```

This is assuming that a field called `text` is stored as a character string, so the constants are put in quotes.  If it is really a number, first I'd be curious why it is called `text`.  In that case, you can dispense with the single quotes.

In your case, the last one doesn't work because `count(text)` counts non-null values.  But the `where` clause only keeps `NULL` values.  For that one, you should use `count(*)`.  The correct query would be:

```
select count(*) from t_test where text is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need for that final query is:

```
select COUNT(*) from t_test where text is null
```

Notice:

- `COUNT(*)` rather than `COUNT(TEXT)` which is null, rendering no values
- `is null` rather than `=null`

Your final set of queries is thus:

```
select COUNT(*) from t_test
select COUNT(text) from t_test where text=5
select COUNT(text) from t_test where text=10
select COUNT(*) from t_test where text is null
```